# Deploy a version at specific time

Tags: c#, asp.net

Do you know a way to manage the deployment of web site at specific time. 
I mean, for example, to start procedure that uploads on test server checkined files at 00:00H

Comment: If your deployment process is automated then I imagine you could schedule a task to perform the operation.  Given the near endless number of ways you *could* be deploying your application, this is a pretty broad and general question.

Comment: There are lots of tools out there. Search for 'automated deployment' and you should find some.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use TFS or Visual Studio Team Services (previously Visual Studio Online), you can create a build scheduled to build and publish a website. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668975.aspx

To publish a website you can use webdeploy or copy files to a shared folder.